# Filling up remaining height with CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a scenario as follow, where i have div with content 1, div with content 2, and a image that takes 100% width (height varies). What i want to achieve is to fit div 1 on top, the image on bottom and remaining with content 2. Do note that all 3 should be fit perfectly into the device view.

I know that using flexbox could help me acheiving above, but i am not sure how to implement it.

Note that i am expecting a pure css solution.

Plunker: [Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lY27AZ2BAwI9p3gjy0bp?p=preview)

```
<ion-view title="Welcome">
  <ion-content has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column;">
    <div style="height: 100%">
      <div style="background-color: red;">
        Content 1 (height based on content)
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 2;">
        Content 2 (remaining height)
      </div>
      <div>
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `<div style="height: 100%">` to make the flexbox layout to work, otherwise that div would be the only flex item, then set `height: 100vh;` on `<ion-content>`.

Or, set that div as the flex container directly if you can't remove it, again need to define the `height` too. Another option would be nested flexbox layout but seems it won't be necessary.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL4zse7z/)**

```
<ion-view title="Welcome">
  <ion-content has-header="true" style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100vh;">
    <div style="background-color: red;">
      Content 1 (height based on content)
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; flex: 1;">
      Content 2 (remaining height)
    </div>
    <div>
      <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" />
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <ion-view title="Welcome">
  <ion-content has-header="true" >
    <div style="height: 100%;" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <div style="background-color: red;">
        Content 1 (height based on content)
      </div>
      <div style="background-color: blue; height:100%;">
        Content 2 (remaining height)
      </div>
      <div>
        <img style="width: 100%;" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).